# In what certificate store should we put server's certificates

Tags: windows, wcf, certificate

Assume system `S` owns a certificate `C`. The following quote suggests that if `C` is to be used by `S's` service apps to authenticate themselves to clients, then `C` should be stored in `LCS`. But if `C` is to be used by `S's` client apps to authenticate themselves to a service, then `C` should be stored inside `CUS`:

> •  The local computer store (LCS).
>   This contains the certificates
>   accessed by machine processes, such as
>   ASP.NET. Use this location to store
>   certificates that authenticate the
>   server to clients.
>
> •  The current user store (CUS). Interactive
>   applications typically place
>   certificates here for the computer's
>   current user. If you are creating a
>   client application, this is where you
>   typically place certificates that
>   authenticate a user to a service.

But next quote sort of negates the above, since it says if `S's` service is embedded in an application that runs under a user account, then certificate `C` should be stored inside `CUS`

> Selecting where to store a certificate
>   depends how and when the service or
>   client runs. The following general
>   rules apply:
>
> • If the service is a Windows service,
>   a service running in "server" mode
>   without any user interface under a
>   Network service account, use the local
>   machine store. Note that administrator
>   privileges are required to install
>   certificates into the local machine
>   store.
>
> • If the service or client is embedded
>   in an application that runs under a
>   user account, then use the current
>   user store.

a) what is meant by *service being embedded within an application*? Is a WCF service running within Net. console application or within Asp.Net application considered to be embedded?

b) And why if app ( which embeds WCF service ) runs under the user account ( even if this account has admin priviliges ), should certificate be located in `CUS`? Does that mean if it is located within `LCS`, then S ( aka client app trying to send this certificate to the server ) won't be able to locate certificate?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) A WCF service running within a .NET console application would be considered an "embedded" service according to that description. This is also referred to as a Self-hosted service.

If the service is running within an ASP.Net application, then it depends on what process is hosting the ASP.Net application, but normally that would be considered a service running in "server" mode.

b) In order for a service to authenticate itself to clients, the user under which the service process runs needs access to the private key corresponding to the certificate. The most convenient way to make this happen is to have the certificate (with private key) installed in the certificate store of the user that runs the process.

It is possible for an application running as any arbitrary user to access a certificate and private key stored in the local computer store as long as security permissions on them allow it.

It all boils down to the identity of the running process and whether it has permission to access the private key associated with the desired certificate.

Comment: "It is possible for an application running as any arbitrary user to access a certificate and private key stored in the local computer store as long as security permissions on them allow it." A - So if user account under which service is running has adequate security permissions, then when this service needs a certificate, it will search both CUS and LCS for it? B - If client app also has adequate permissions, could we also put its certificate inside LCS?

Comment: BTW - I've edited b) question in my original post, since it was kind of ambiguous - just telling you in case your answer isn't valid for edited question

Comment: "A WCF service running within a .NET console application would be considered an "embedded" service according to that description. This is also referred to as a Self-hosted service." May I ask what is the definition of an embedded service?

Comment: I don't have a definition for "embedded service." I'm just referring to the nomenclature presented in the question. I interpret it to mean that a WCF ServiceHost object has been instantiated, configured and opened within an application running as a regular user process in Windows.